# Why doesn't Spark change the physical plan after caching?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, caching

I'm trying to understand how caching of some dataframes alters the physical plan.
Its my understanding that if a dataframe is cached then subsequent computation that uses that dataframe should not re-evaluate the operations needed by the dataframe.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a difference between caching the result and un-persisting it afterwards (which should clear the cache and restore the original physical plan.

example of `df.explain(mode='simple')` before `cache().count()`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- InMemoryTableScan [idx#12021L, (REDACTED), ... 32 more fields], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
...
```

after `df.cache().count()`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- InMemoryTableScan [idx#12021L, (REDACTED), ... 32 more fields], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            +- AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
...
```

How would you explain that the physical plan is the same, and that it's not final? Should be final after its execution.

By the way, this is my spark conf:

```
             .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
             .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g")
             .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g")
             .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
             .config("spark.sql.execution.pythonUDF.arrow.enabled", "true")
             .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch", "10000")
             .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.selfDestruct.enabled", "true")
             .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled","false")
             .config("spark.logConf", "true")  # allows us to change the log level later in the code
             .config("spark.ui.port", 4042)
             .config("spark.eventLog.dir", config["local_log_dir"])
             .config("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", False)
             .config("spark.python.profile","false")
             .config("spark.sql.constraintPropagation.enabled","false")
             .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", True)
             .config("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", True)
```

I'm surprised to see that `isFinalPlan` is kept as `false`.
what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you're supplying us in your question, it seems like your table is already cached (or somehow in memory) to begin with. The `InMemoryTableScan` node in your query plan hints to that.

In general, caching should have an influence on your query plan. Let's see a simple example where I'm just reading a random CSV file on disk:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ";").csv("./csvWithArrays.csv")

df.select(F.col("Id")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
FileScan csv [Id#17] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/some-path/csvWithArrays.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema
: struct<Id:string>

print(df.cache().count())

df.select(F.col("Id")).explain())
== Physical Plan ==
InMemoryTableScan [Id#17]
   +- InMemoryRelation [Id#17, Subject#18, Marks#19], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- FileScan csv [Id#17,Subject#18,Marks#19] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/some-path/csvWithArrays.csv], PartitionFilters: [
], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<Id:string,Subject:string,Marks:string>
```

As you can see, after caching an extra `InMemoryRelation` and `InMemoryTableScan` node are added to the tree.

Maybe have a look at how your `df` is defined (is it read on disk? from a certain file? from a stream? ...?) to figure out why your `df` is already in memory before you do that last `.cache()` operation. For educational purposes, I would also suggest to put `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` on `False`. This will make your query plan more easy to interpret.